# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/get/' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I am trying to connect Django and React, I made an API in Django and calling that api from React app. But I am getting

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/get?date=03.24.2023&job_id=131315' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I know there are lots question on this topic, but none of those seem to solve in my case

This is my settings.py file

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-(!kg*t#pzv!q6%xgap@)wg)dm8@lrtmh2x&f5yf5u15p7tmoc5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'analyzer_util.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'analyzer_util.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

api call :

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def get_log_details(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_dict = request.query_params
        response_obj = service.get_log_details(query_dict['date'], query_dict['job_id'])

        return Response(response_obj.serialize, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

And this is my api call from React:

```
  axios.get('http://localhost/api/get?date=03.24.2023&job_id=131315/').then(function (response) {
    // axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/get/', config).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

request headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/get?date=03.24.2023&job_id=131315/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

response headers:

```
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Wed, 24 May 2023 09:57:57 GMT
Location: /api/get/?date=03.24.2023&job_id=131315/
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.5
Vary: origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

can anyone see what I am doing wrong, stuck in this since 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS: True` in your `settings.py` as it documented here: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_allow_all_origins-bool

Btw, look like your API (`http://localhost/api/get/`) is missing port (for example, the correct url should be `http://localhost:5000/api/get/` if it open on port 5000). Try test your API with Postman to see if it's working or not.

Comment: I tried it again, it is not working, actuallt I tired all the combinations of CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS I could find on other answer and documentation, none worked. And in api it does contain the port in actual code, I guess I missed it here while posting.

Comment: How about the others settings? Such as 
`CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
'accept',
'content-type',
'origin',
'user-agent',
]` 
 or  `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:5000/api/get/"]` like this.

If none of this works, then open dev tools, in `Network` tab to debug, or see if the headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` is set

Comment: Nope, it is not working. And headers does not contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

Comment: I have added the headers above in the question